# Problema ao ler arquivos binários!

Tags: c, arquivo, estrutura-de-dados

Estou fazendo um método para um código em C que adiciona um acréscimo no valor de todos os livros gravados em um arquivo binário, entretanto ... quando tenho mais de 2 registros, todos em diante, ou seja o registro 3,4,5 ... são reescritos com os valores do registro 2 alguém pode me ajudar?
{

```
FILE *fptr;
float acrescimo;
struct reg_livro livro;
int contadorLivros = 0;

if((fptr = fopen("livros.dat","rb+"))==NULL){
    printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo \n");
    return;
}

fseek(fptr,0,2);
int tamanhoArq = ftell(fptr);
int qtdLivros = tamanhoArq/sizeof(livro);

printf("Quantidade de livros %d\n", qtdLivros);
printf("Tamanho do arquivo %d\n",tamanhoArq );
rewind(fptr);
printf("Posicao atual %d\n",ftell(fptr) );

printf("Informe a porcentagem de acrescimo no preco de cada livro\n");
fflush(stdin);scanf("%f",&acrescimo);

while(contadorLivros<qtdLivros)
{   
    fread(&livro,sizeof(livro),1,fptr);
    printf("\n Ponteiro Inicial %d",ftell(fptr));
    float valorAcrescimo = livro.preco*(acrescimo/100);
    printf("\n Acrescimo: %f\n", valorAcrescimo);
    printf("\n Livro antes da alteracao: %f ",livro.preco);
    livro.preco = livro.preco + valorAcrescimo;
    printf("\n Livro depois da alteracao: %f ",livro.preco);

    fseek(fptr,-sizeof(livro),1);
    fwrite(&livro,sizeof(livro),1,fptr);
    printf("\n Ponteiro Final %d",ftell(fptr));
    contadorLivros++;

}

fclose(fptr);
printf("\n Acrescimo inserido com sucesso!!\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui pôr o código que você escreveu para rodar, já que ele precisa de outras funções, bem como um arquivo "livros.dat" preexistente; mas se os registros 3 em diante estão sendo sobrescritos com as informações do registro 2, a probabilidade é que o `fread()` esteja falhando a partir daí, mas você não está verificando o valor de retorno para conferir que a leitura funcionou...

Sendo assim, sugiro substituir o `fread()` pelo seguinte:

```
while (contadorLivros < qtdLivros) {
    int rc = fread(&livro, sizeof (livro), 1, fptr);
    if (rc < 1) { // Não consegui ler ao menos um elemento
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro ao ler registro nº %d: ferror() retornou %d\n", contadorLivros + 1, ferror(fptr));
    }
    printf("\n Ponteiro Inicial %d",ftell(fptr));
```

Adicionalmente, talvez convenha mover o ponteiro do arquivo para o valor absoluto do registro, em vez do valor relativo, usando `fseek(fptr, contadorLivros * sizeof (livro), 0);` antes do `fread()` e do `fwrite()`.